# npm equivalent of yarn install --check-files (or yarn check)

Tags: npm, dependencies, yarnpkg, package.json, lockfile

**Update for 2020**

This question originally referred to the `yarn check` command, but [the docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check/#toc-yarn-check) state that this is deprecated in v1, and removed in v2, and `yarn install --check-files` should be used instead.

Unfortunately there is *still*, apparently, no equivalent of the `--check-files` flag in `npm install`!

---

As part of my development build I'd like to check that the versions of dependencies in `node_modules` are what's expected to be there according to both what's specified in `package.json` and the lockfile `package-lock.json`.

In yarn you can do this with `yarn install --check-files` (or the older [deprecated](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/check/#toc-yarn-check) `yarn check` command in v1)

**I am trying to achieve the same using npm.**

At the moment I am using `npm ci` ([see docs here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ci)) which does work, in the sense that it completely reinstalls `node_modules` from what's in the lockfile and then errors if the versions in `package.json` don't match.

But, this is a bit heavyweight and slow. I'm wondering if there is a purely static way to run these checks with npm that doesn't involve cleaning and reinstalling everything on disk?

Answer (score 0):

I believe `npm prune` ([docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-prune)) is what you are looking for.